# what has mistaken with the switch command in C?

Tags: c

Here i just experienced with the switch command and if command at C. I have omitted the if command by comment and wrote the same command by using switch command. But its now working as i gave the instruction. Where i have mistaken? As i am a learner please pardon my mistakes..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        char card_name[3];
        puts("enter the card name: ");
        scanf("%2s", card_name);
        /*int val=0;
        if (card_name[0]=='K') {
            val=10;
        } else if (card_name[0]=='Q'){
            val=10;
        } else if (card_name[0]=='J'){
            val=10;
        } else if (card_name[0]=='A'){
            val=11;
        }else{
            val=atoi(card_name);
        }*/
        int val=0;
        switch (card_name[0]) {
            case 'K':
            case 'Q':
            case 'J':
            val=10;
            break;
            case 'A':
            val=11;
            default:
            val=atoi(card_name);
            break;
        }
        if (val>2 && val<7) {
            puts("the count has gone up!");
        } else if(val>=10){
            puts("The count has gone down");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is...?

Comment: I find your question a bit unspecific - what exactly is happening (which instruction are you talking about?). However you are definitely missing a `break` in `case 'A'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `break;` for `case 'A'` .. Is that intentional ?

Comment: Oh shit.. Thanks for the help.. No that was the mistake. as i am new in c i have missed the silly thing.

Comment: @Sahriarrahmansupto .. relax mate .. we all do it

Comment: Can you suggest me some good ebook to learn C more easily??

Comment: @Sahriarrahmansupto This is the ebook of a very popular C learning book : C programming language ( K & R ) .. http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2008/resource/The_C_Programming_Language.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You're missing another break in the `'A'` case. Your switch statement then should look something like this (I added indentation for you).

```
switch (card_name[0]) {
    case 'K':
    case 'Q':
    case 'J':
        val=10;
        break;
    case 'A':
        val=11;
        break; // you were missing a break statement here
    default:
        val=atoi(card_name);
        break;
}
```

Comment: he may not want to use break for case 'a' ..

Comment: Well, looking at the commented out if statement, he wants a 10 for K, Q, and J, 11 for A, and the result of atoi for everything else. Adding the break statement would thus make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a break statement in case 'A':,before the default label. You should break after each statement in a case statement unless it was your intent to have the other cases execute, as well as a given case.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there might have some silly mistakes and here is it. Thanks for the co-operation to learn the mistakes..